# Изменение стиля индикаторов в слайдере с reactstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

Привет!Я установил слайдер от reactstrap на свой сайт но у него индикаторы сделаны полосками, а мне хотелось бы чтобы они были белыми кружками а когда не выбран элемент то серыми кружками и стрелочки контролов  были в кружочках.
[image: То как мой сайт выглядит сейчас]

Slider.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Carousel,
  CarouselItem,
  CarouselControl,
  CarouselIndicators,
  CarouselCaption
} from 'reactstrap';

const items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    altText: 'Slide 1',
    caption: 'Slide 1'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    altText: 'Slide 2',
    caption: 'Slide 2'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    altText: 'Slide 3',
    caption: 'Slide 3'
  }
];

class Slider extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { activeIndex: 0 };
    this.next = this.next.bind(this);
    this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
    this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
    this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
    this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);
  }

  onExiting() {
    this.animating = true;
  }

  onExited() {
    this.animating = false;
  }

  next() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  previous() {
    if (this.animating) return;
    const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
  }

  goToIndex(newIndex) {
    if (this.animating) return;
    this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
  }

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;

    const slides = items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <CarouselItem
          className="custom-tag"
          tag="div"
          key={item.id}
          onExiting={this.onExiting}
          onExited={this.onExited}
        >
 </CarouselItem>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <style>
          {
            `.custom-tag {
                max-width: 100%;
                height: 500px;
                background: black;
              }`
          }
        </style>
        <Carousel
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          next={this.next}
          previous={this.previous}
        >
          <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
          {slides}
          <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
          <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
        </Carousel>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Slider;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import FaAlignJustify from 'react-icons/lib/fa/align-justify';
import FaShoppingCart from 'react-icons/lib/fa/shopping-cart';
import FaSearch from 'react-icons/lib/fa/search';
import Slider from "./Slider";


class Header extends Component {
     render() {
         return(
         <div>
             <div className="HeaderMain">
             <div className="DropMenu" >
             <ul className ="MenuButtons" id="TopNav" >
                     <li className="MenuHeader"><FaAlignJustify /></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><img src="/images/portland.jpg" alt="portlandlogo"/></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Devices</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Delivery & Payment</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Guarantee</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                     <li className="Visible"><div className="CartMain">
                < FaShoppingCart /><span>Cart</span>
                <div className="Cart-container"><span className="Cart-span"></span><span className="Cart-text">0</span></div></div></li>
                <li className="Visible"><button className="HeaderBtn">Sign in</button></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="SecondMenuMain">
                <ul className="SecondMenu">
                    <li><a href="#">TOP SALES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BRAND FOCUS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HI-TECH</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BEST SELLERS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" className="Support">SUPPORT</a></li>
                    <li className="Bordered"><div><FaSearch className="Search" /><input placeholder="I`m looking for..."/></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div>

            </div>   
                    <Slider />>
            </div>
         </div>);


    }
}

export default Header;
```

App.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-regular';
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Montserrat Regular.svg#Montserrat Regular') format('svg');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold';
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot');
  src: url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Montserrat SemiBold.svg#Montserrat SemiBold') format('svg');
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  unicode-range: U+0020-2044;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  background-color: #B9BED1 !important;
  color: #B9BED1 !important;
  height: 1px;
}

/* ______________________________________________________________________________ШАПКА САЙТА(Header.js) */

.MenuButtons {
  margin-top: 37px;
}

.MenuButtons>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.MenuButtons>li>a {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 29px;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.MenuButtons>li>div>span {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}

.MenuButtons>li>img {
  margin-right: 157px;
}

.Cart-container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.Cart-span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 50% 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.Cart-text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0em 0.65em;
}

.CartMain {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 29px;
}

.HeaderMain {
  display: inline;
  color: #343e5c;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.HeaderBtn {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  width: 85px;
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #e3e8f0;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #343e5c
}

.DropMenu {
  margin-left: 115px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.MenuHeader {
  margin-right: 75px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1159px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    margin-right: 75px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:1073px) {
  .DropMenu {
    margin-left: 35px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>a {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:991px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>a {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:550px) {
  .MenuHeader {
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }
  .DropMenu {
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:443px) {
  .MenuButtons>li>img {
    display: none;
  }
  .CartMain {
    margin-left: 50px;
  }
}

.SecondMenuMain {
  margin-left: 115px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.SecondMenu>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.SecondMenu>li>a,
.SecondMenu>li>div>input {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b9bed1;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1.1px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.SecondMenu>li>a:hover {
  color: #343e5c;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
}

.SecondMenu>li>div>input {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold', sans-serif;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b9bed1;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

.SecondMenu>li>div>input:focus {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.Support {
  padding-left: 280px;
}

.Bordered {
  border-left: 1px solid #b9bed1;
  border-right: 1px solid #b9bed1;
}

.Search {
  margin-left: 21px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто в своих стилях перезаписываете классы `.carousel-indicators li`. 
К примеру для индикатора:

```
.carousel-indicators li {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.carousel-indicators .active {
    background-color: #fefefe;
}
```

Пример для кнопок:

```
.carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
    color: blue;
}
.carousel-control-prev:hover {
    color: #fefefe;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]